# mysql- 3 random records for main departments with multiple level depth of subdepartments

Tags: mysql

I am trying make a complex query in MySQL i have following two tables

```
departments                                 employees

Id    parent    title               id  name    department   status
---------------------------       ------------------------------------
1     0         Health              1   abc     3              1
2     0         Sports              2   def     3              1
3     0         Education           3   ghi     5              1
4     1         Physical            4   jkl     10             1
5     1         Mental              5   kkk     6              1
6     2         Football            6   lll     6              1
7     2         Baseball            7   sss     8              1
8     2         Beachball           8   xxx     6              1
9     2         Hockey              9   yyy     6              1
10    4         ENT                 10  zzz     7              1
11    0         Finance             11  mnb     11             1
```

Departments table have four main departments(i-e: parent = 0) with multiple level depths of sub-departments.

Currently i have done it through a PHP function by running queries multiple time to achieve this, but still i want know if this is possible to fetch it with a Query.
Whats the best way OR how to select max 3 employee randomly for each main department with status 1.

The expected result should be something like

```
id  name    department   maindep
1   abc     3            3
2   def     3            3
3   ghi     5            1
4   jkl     10           1
5   kkk     6            2
7   sss     8            2
10  zzz     7            2
11  mnb    11            11
```

Comment: Show us your current code and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Jocelyn apologies for confusing English. I am trying but haven't figured out anything yet ... feels like struck